# how to display wp tags in dropdwon with checkbox in admin

Tags: wordpress

I have Install WordPress and i need all tags should be display in drop down like category

Also I want search filter over there

when i want to put any comma separate tag in search box all tag should be checked in drop down automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get all the tags in the WP.

```
$tags = get_tags(array('get'=>'all'));
```

example,

```
$tags = get_tags(array('get'=>'all'));
    $output .= '<ul class="tag-cloud-list">';
        if($tags) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag):
        $output .= '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($tag).'">'. $tag->name .'</a></li>';
        endforeach;
        } else {
        _e('No tags created.', 'text-domain');
        }
    $output .= '</ul>';
return $output;
```

The same way you can use the checkbox in the place of UL and LI. Also, you can use the add_meta_box() to add the tags to the all post type.

For more details, Please visit.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_tags/